# Is XNA for iOS overkill?

Tags: xna, monotouch

I'm working on iPAD game using MonoTouch which is similar to an IQ testing game. At the moment, I can write some simple games using basic UIImages and animations.

I'm wondering if I should learn XNA to create a game where people can throw a ball against a wall and see it bounce.

Has anyone seen any good examples of tutorials using XNA for simple 2d games?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't "XNA for iOS". You can use [MonoGame](https://www.monogame.net), an attempt to recreate the functionality of XNA under Mono. And yes, you can do a lot of things with it (if you stick to 2D games, they don't have 3D support yet); and you *should* use lower-level APIs like this if you are creating more complex, performance-demanding games.

Check MonoGame's site (previously linked) for examples of successful games published on iOS.

Comment: An alternative (also based on MonoTouch) is EXEN which I think is more widely used then MonoGame http://andrewrussell.net/exen/ (not sure though)

Comment: ExEn isn't being actively developed any more. That's a big bummer if you want long-term support and features.